# How to insert an Intent in a Navigation Activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a simple and plain **Navigation Activity** and I would like to edit the bar's **content**.

1st how do I put an **Intent** to open another Activity when clicking on one of the items? I know I have to put a **findViewById**+**setOnClickListener** method somewhere, but what is the **ID** of every item in the list? Speaking of which, this code has to be put in the **NavigationDrawerFragment** class, correct?

2nd how do I add/remove **items**? I know how to rename them, but where do I find them in the classes, exactly?

The code is rather straight forward as it's the very same that come as default in Android Studio

```
package com.dashopper.marco.prova;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
 * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you speaking of Navigation Drawer project template of Android Studio? If so, the template wouldn't use `Activities` via `Intents` but `Fragments` (by default). Do you date to use `Activities`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed talking about a Navigation Drawer, theres a nice [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) that explains the process. Just Scroll down to the Navigation Drawer part if you wish (but the other stuff about material design is pretty cool.
Just to make sure you understand, each item in the drawer should start a fragment and not an activity. This is pivotal.

Also heres the [Android Design Blog](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-content) which gives a very nice detailed explanation on how you should design the navigation drawer!

Comment: Hi Shrey, thanks for the effort. Yet, the second link has no coding, tutorial, nor anything. Regarding the first one, I can't even make it to the first checkpoint. What's ".activity.MainActivity"? The emulator crashes when I try to force it open the app, maybe because I am using API 19?
Any idea about where I can find a good tutorial with the explanation of how can I link items in a Navigation drawer to another activity?

Comment: Heres a link from the google developers website itself: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

You may need to add the related support libraries in your gradle build file if necessary. If you dont know what that means: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Comment: I personally dislike the android developer, I don't find complete scripts. I am not a pro, and for instance, knowing what to import in the class would be much useful!
I have this navigation drawer, when I click on the items it brings up fragment. I just want to open new activity, like Google + or Nike Running app. How do I do that?